# how to fetch data after clicking on dropdown box

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi i m new in codeigniter plz help me.  In my db there is one table name car details.i am fetching city field in drop down box so its work well.now after clicking on specific city i have to fetch all the data  so how its possible.plz help me

**model file**

```
function getCity()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->query('select DISTINCT mco_registercity from cardetailso');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        return array();
```

**contoller file**

```
$data['cities'] = $this->car_model->get_city();
```

**view file**

```
<?php foreach($city as $each){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $each->mco_registercity; ?>">
<?php echo $each->mco_registercity; ?></option>';
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You need `javascript`, i guess :D

Comment: **after clicking on selected city i have to redirect to another page.so how i can use redirect function**

Comment: as I said, you need javascript to do that, take a look: http://api.jquery.com/change/  and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //in view file
 <select name="something" id="something" onchange="getCityDetails(this.value);">
 <?php foreach($city as $each){ ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $each->mco_registercity; ?>">
 <?php echo $each->mco_registercity; ?></option>';
 <?php } ?>
 </select>

  //in JAVASCRIPT SECTION 

  function getCityDetails(city)
  {
      //make ajax call with the city value
  }
```

Hope it will help you. Please let me know if you need any further help.